# Atom v1.32 stopped detecting matching tags and JavaScript syntax highlighting

Tags: atom-editor

After v1.32.0 update, atom just stopped detecting matching html tags, and javascript/typescript color scheme changed (variables, functions, classes, object keys, etc...).

Is it possible to reactivate matching html tags highlighting and use the previous javascript color scheme that I was used to already?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the [release notes](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.32.0), Atom v1.32 enabled the new [tree-sitter](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter) parser. Try enabling/disabling it to see whether that restores the old behaviour:

[image]

*Screenshot: Toggle Tree Sitter Parsers in the Atom Core Settings*

**Update:**

Atom v1.32.1 fixes [several issues](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/tag/v1.32.1) related to syntax highlighting. Since Tree Sitter is now the default highlighter, you should probably keep using it, unless the old highlighters serve you better.

Comment: Amazing! That solved the problem, everything is restored now! Thank you very much!

Comment: https://github.com/gandm/language-babel/issues/510 <-- there's a small workaround (add a customFileType inside config.cson) in this thread - which will do until language-babel patch for the new TreeSitter parser. So now you can have babel syntax recognition for js/jsx *and* TreeSitter parsing for everything else.