# Atom text editor colors are changed randomly

Tags: atom-editor

In the last couple of months, weird thing happen to Atom on my laptop (and also on my mac - recently tested).
Randomly, the colors of the  text editor are being changed completely. Its like the styles.scss is somehow overriden, but it's same as default file, no changes made.
Even clearing window state, or opening on safe mode - doesn't help.
The only thing that helps is re-installing - and also then, after few days of works - suddenly it happens again!

Am i going crazy or this issue is known?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Atom v1.32 stopped detecting matching tags and JavaScript syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988349/atom-v1-32-stopped-detecting-matching-tags-and-javascript-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: @idleberg Yes. Thanks!